# Aramex throws "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'Shipping.wsdl'"

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, aramex

I am working on the [Aramex shipping API](http://www.aramex.com/developers/aramex-apis/42194/Shipping-Services-API). I have downloaded the PHP file and also the WSDL file. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    $soapClient = new SoapClient('Shipping.wsdl');
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($soapClient->__getFunctions());

    $params = array(
            'Shipments' => array(
                'Shipment' => array(
                        'Shipper'   => array(
                                        'Reference1'    => 'Ref 111111',
                                        'Reference2'    => 'Ref 222222',
                                        'AccountNumber' => '20016',
                                        'PartyAddress'  => array(
                                            'Line1'                 => 'Mecca St',
                                            'Line2'                 => '',
                                            'Line3'                 => '',
                                            'City'                  => 'Amman',
                                            'StateOrProvinceCode'   => '',
                                            'PostCode'              => '',
                                            'CountryCode'           => 'Jo'
                                        ),
                                        'Contact'       => array(
                                            'Department'            => '',
                                            'PersonName'            => 'Michael',
                                            'Title'                 => '',
                                            'CompanyName'           => 'Aramex',
                                            'PhoneNumber1'          => '5555555',
                                            'PhoneNumber1Ext'       => '125',
                                            'PhoneNumber2'          => '',
                                            'PhoneNumber2Ext'       => '',
                                            'FaxNumber'             => '',
                                            'CellPhone'             => '07777777',
                                            'EmailAddress'          => 'michael@aramex.com',
                                            'Type'                  => ''
                                        ),
                        ),

                        'Consignee' => array(
                                        'Reference1'    => 'Ref 333333',
                                        'Reference2'    => 'Ref 444444',
                                        'AccountNumber' => '',
                                        'PartyAddress'  => array(
                                            'Line1'                 => '15 ABC St',
                                            'Line2'                 => '',
                                            'Line3'                 => '',
                                            'City'                  => 'Dubai',
                                            'StateOrProvinceCode'   => '',
                                            'PostCode'              => '',
                                            'CountryCode'           => 'AE'
                                        ),

                                        'Contact'       => array(
                                            'Department'            => '',
                                            'PersonName'            => 'Mazen',
                                            'Title'                 => '',
                                            'CompanyName'           => 'Aramex',
                                            'PhoneNumber1'          => '6666666',
                                            'PhoneNumber1Ext'       => '155',
                                            'PhoneNumber2'          => '',
                                            'PhoneNumber2Ext'       => '',
                                            'FaxNumber'             => '',
                                            'CellPhone'             => '',
                                            'EmailAddress'          => 'mazen@aramex.com',
                                            'Type'                  => ''
                                        ),
                        ),

                        'ThirdParty' => array(
                                        'Reference1'    => '',
                                        'Reference2'    => '',
                                        'AccountNumber' => '',
                                        'PartyAddress'  => array(
                                            'Line1'                 => '',
                                            'Line2'                 => '',
                                            'Line3'                 => '',
                                            'City'                  => '',
                                            'StateOrProvinceCode'   => '',
                                            'PostCode'              => '',
                                            'CountryCode'           => ''
                                        ),
                                        'Contact'       => array(
                                            'Department'            => '',
                                            'PersonName'            => '',
                                            'Title'                 => '',
                                            'CompanyName'           => '',
                                            'PhoneNumber1'          => '',
                                            'PhoneNumber1Ext'       => '',
                                            'PhoneNumber2'          => '',
                                            'PhoneNumber2Ext'       => '',
                                            'FaxNumber'             => '',
                                            'CellPhone'             => '',
                                            'EmailAddress'          => '',
                                            'Type'                  => ''                           
                                        ),
                        ),

                        'Reference1'                => 'Shpt 0001',
                        'Reference2'                => '',
                        'Reference3'                => '',
                        'ForeignHAWB'               => 'ABC 000111',
                        'TransportType'             => 0,
                        'ShippingDateTime'          => time(),
                        'DueDate'                   => time(),
                        'PickupLocation'            => 'Reception',
                        'PickupGUID'                => '',
                        'Comments'                  => 'Shpt 0001',
                        'AccountingInstrcutions'    => '',
                        'OperationsInstructions'    => '',

                        'Details' => array(
                                        'Dimensions' => array(
                                            'Length'                => 10,
                                            'Width'                 => 10,
                                            'Height'                => 10,
                                            'Unit'                  => 'cm',

                                        ),

                                        'ActualWeight' => array(
                                            'Value'                 => 0.5,
                                            'Unit'                  => 'Kg'
                                        ),

                                        'ProductGroup'          => 'EXP',
                                        'ProductType'           => 'PDX',
                                        'PaymentType'           => 'P',
                                        'PaymentOptions'        => '',
                                        'Services'              => '',
                                        'NumberOfPieces'        => 1,
                                        'DescriptionOfGoods'    => 'Docs',
                                        'GoodsOriginCountry'    => 'Jo',

                                        'CashOnDeliveryAmount'  => array(
                                            'Value'                 => 0,
                                            'CurrencyCode'          => ''
                                        ),

                                        'InsuranceAmount'       => array(
                                            'Value'                 => 0,
                                            'CurrencyCode'          => ''
                                        ),

                                        'CollectAmount'         => array(
                                            'Value'                 => 0,
                                            'CurrencyCode'          => ''
                                        ),

                                        'CashAdditionalAmount'  => array(
                                            'Value'                 => 0,
                                            'CurrencyCode'          => ''                           
                                        ),

                                        'CashAdditionalAmountDescription' => '',

                                        'CustomsValueAmount' => array(
                                            'Value'                 => 0,
                                            'CurrencyCode'          => ''                               
                                        ),

                                        'Items'                 => array(

                                        )
                        ),
                ),
        ),

            'ClientInfo'            => array(
                                        'AccountCountryCode'    => 'JO',
                                        'AccountEntity'         => 'AMM',
                                        'AccountNumber'         => '20016',
                                        'AccountPin'            => '221321',
                                        'UserName'              => 'reem@reem.com',
                                        'Password'              => '123456789',
                                        'Version'               => '1.0'
                                    ),

            'Transaction'           => array(
                                        'Reference1'            => '001',
                                        'Reference2'            => '', 
                                        'Reference3'            => '', 
                                        'Reference4'            => '', 
                                        'Reference5'            => '',                                  
                                    ),
            'LabelInfo'             => array(
                                        'ReportID'              => 9201,
                                        'ReportType'            => 'URL',
            ),
    );

    $params['Shipments']['Shipment']['Details']['Items'][] = array(
        'PackageType'   => 'Box',
        'Quantity'      => 1,
        'Weight'        => array(
                'Value'     => 0.5,
                'Unit'      => 'Kg',        
        ),
        'Comments'      => 'Docs',
        'Reference'     => ''
    );

    print_r($params);

    try {
        $auth_call = $soapClient->CreateShipments($params);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($auth_call);
        die();
    } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
        die('Error : ' . $fault->faultstring);
    }
?>
```

But my code is throwing the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'Shipping.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "Shipping.wsdl" in F:\xampp\htdocs\test\aramex.php:5 Stack trace: #0 F:\xampp\htdocs\test\aramex.php(5): SoapClient->SoapClient('Shipping.wsdl') #1 {main} thrown in F:\xampp\htdocs\test\aramex.php on line 5

I have tried to change some setting in my *php.ini* file, but it throws the same error. What do I have to do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide full path to Shipping.wsdl.  It can be an URI or Local path to hard drive ...

Answer (score 1):

If anybody else is looking for the answer, this is how it was loaded now.

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("https://ws.dev.aramex.net/ShippingAPI.V2/Shipping/Service_1_0.svc?wsdl");
```